# An inline frame that behave like a single-cell table

Tags: adobe-indesign

Here is a simple test:

1. Create a new document with a primary text frame option enabled.
2. Type there:

   ```
   line 1
   <empty line 1>
   <empty line 2>
   <empty line 3>
   line 2
   ```
3. By using the Type tool, create a new, small text frame. Type there:

   ```
   line a
   line b
   ```

   and paste this frame on the second empty line to make it inline.

   [image]
4. Put the cursor in the end of the line "a", press Enter, and then Backspace. Notice that after pressing the Backspace, there will be two (why??) empty lines below it.

   *(Note: The wrapping of the inline frame is currently set to "Jump object".)*

   [image]

My question: Why there are two and not one empty lines after pressing the Backspace? How can I adjust the settings so that there will be no additional empty lines created there?

That is, I want to know how to create an inline frame that will behave like a single-cell table.

btw, I don't really care whether such frame will be inline or not. It can be anchored to a specific character instead, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>(I'm using CS6. Both text frames are set to auto-size vertically, and the pasted frame wrap is set to jump content with 0 offsets.  I would anticipate that the amount of nudging necessary in this answer will be related to text formatting for the paragraphs - outer paragraph text is set to 11/auto, pasted frame paragraph text is set to 11/16.)</sup>

---

Described behavior:

[image]

The issue appears to generally be due to the fact the pasted frame aligns to the *baseline* of the encompassing paragraph.

Nudge the pasted frame down to get relatively close to centering that ¶ marker on the pasted frame.

[image]

After nudging, the behavior is as expected:

[image]

My Nudge setting is at 0p1. As I nudge there's an initial large gap created... I keep nudging down until I see the *next* large gap created, then nudge up once. From there, the behavior is as expected. (Note, baseline shift *doesn't* work here.)

[image]

---

Depending upon *where* the cursor is when pasting, the pasted frame *may* align to the leading of the encompassing paragraph rather than the baseline. Simply look at the ¶ as it's related to the pasted frame. If it is at the top... reverse this and nudge *up* rather than down.

I did try and find other methods to align the pasted frame within it's enclosing paragraph (frame options, baseline shift, etc.), but nothing was fruitful. Nudging seemed to be the only thing which worked, at least on my system with CS6.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error here in InDesign 2021 but I get it from time to time. Especially with combinations of anchored objects, auto-sizing, snap to baseline and text wrap. In my experience it often helps to just nudge the *outer* frame back and forth a step. Or of course to cut out the anchored object and paste it back in.

Comment: It's really odd.. on rare occasions the hidden ¶ marker is at the top of the pasted frame, most often its at the bottom. I can't seem to work out *why* there's a change in that aspect.