# Text not wrapping around anchored image InDesign CC

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, typesetting, creative-cloud, text-wrap

I am wanting title and description of burger to sit alongside the burger image. The first burger image uses the wrap around bounding box option.

[image]

[image]

I want the following burger image and text to behave the same way however whenever I select the wrap around bounding box option again it doesn't behave in the same way. I am not familiar with placing anchored images with text.

[image: t]

Comment: You could use the option under the blue dot in the text wrap dialog, (in your image above), to wrap it around the image instead of the bounding box. Then use the options in the dialog to push it away from the image edges to your liking.

Comment: I think, ultimately the behavior is similar to this: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/156046/an-inline-frame-that-behave-like-a-single-cell-table/156047#156047 It's about *where* the object is in relation to the paragraph returns. Nudging it up or down may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another, possibly easier way to approach this is to **indent** the paragraphs in the text box, and **disable wrapping** on the images. That way you would **not** have to unpuzzle how the wrapping options affect the text flow.